# how to get same sized launcher icons on different emulator skins…(android)

Tags: android, emulation, density-independent-pixel

have a look at figure 2. in the link given below.. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html..

there it is being mentioned that ,The platform provides density independence to applications by default.(launcher icons are displayed at the same physical sizes, although screen sizes, aspect ratios, and densities are different.)

and showed with 3 emulator screens namely WVGA high density (left), HVGA medium density (center), and QVGA low density (right)...

i have created these 3 avd's and tested but the launcher icons are different in different emulator..can any one knows why it so and how should i get same sized launcher icons on those emulators...

Comment: What do you mean by different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should refer this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 different drawable folder name drawable-mdpi/,drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi/ in your res/ folder and each of them have different size icon. if you want same size icon in each emulator then put the same size icon in all three folders.

Comment: not only my icon even the default android launcher icons are also looking different sized on different emulator screen.....

Comment: android launcher icons have there height and width in dip not in px and due to dip android launcher icons will scale according to density of screen. create two new AVD with default skin launch first, when you launch 2nd change its dpi value and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your monitor is of a fixed pixel density, while these various devices will have differing pixel density. That means the same number of pixels will be a different physical size on your monitor than it will be on an Android device (which will typically have much smaller pixels than your monitor).